# JOOQ Format tex from column

Tags: java, sql, jooq

I have column with type of text where i stored xml, I want to format it in my query using jooq. Example:

```
<note>
    <to>Tove</to>
    <from>Jani</from>
    <heading>Reminder</heading>
    <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

My target is to remove spaces from start of the line and remove newlines, in results i want to have text as single line :

```
<note><to>Tove</to><from>Jani</from><heading>Reminder</heading><body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body></note>
```

As you see i delete all newlines and spaces beetwen start of the line and text. So is there any way to do that using jooq ?

Answer (score 0):

The way I understand your question, you'd like this XML "normalisation" to happen whenever jOOQ reads the XML content form your database, and your XML content is really just a `String`. In that case, you can implement a simple [`Converter<String, String>`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Converter.html) and apply that converter to your generated code:
https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/custom-data-types

If you're not using the code generator, you can create your own data types as follows:

```java
DataType<String> XML_TYPE = SQLDataType.VARCHAR.asConvertedDataType(new MyConverter());
Field<String> field = DSL.field("my_column", XML_TYPE);

Result<Record1<String>> result =
DSL.using(configuration)
   .select(field)
   .from(...)
   .fetch();
```